# Error while trying to update drivers for NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

i've been using ubuntu 20.04 for quite some time now, also have the NVIDIA Quadro P600.
after seeing the same error over and over, decided to investigate:
The error: after some time with the computer on - the menus (when i try to shutdown, restart etc.) are gone missing (i can hover over them, but can't see the text).
assumed it's the gpu drivers (after all - it's visual), then decided to try and update. i did the apt-get update and upgrade just to be on the safe side.
then tried to update using this command:

```
'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-dkms-510'
```

and i've been getting this over and over:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzHw2.png)
(as shown on picture attached)
don't know what to do. i've been trying to update via system update (gui version) - been getting some huge errors but i can take screenshot since it's bigger than my screen LOL

i would very much appreciate the help

Comment: 1) Please don't post screenshots of text. 2) Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @nobody i've changed my regional settings to the main server, then tried again. no luck. still getting the same error messages. as for your question Pilot6, i did and didn't get anything special. my system is up to date

Answer (score 1):

The problem with images from terminal output, you can not read it complete.

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

renames your current one.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Restores the default sources.list. Refresh information what is available on packages.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

then try again.